# React-vis: Is it possible to set a minimum height to verticalBarSeries bars?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-vis

I'm building a stacked vertical bar series chart with values that oscillate between 1 and 1.000.000, so the bars that show really low values can't be seen (the values in the top x-axis are divided by 1.000).

### [image]

Is it possible to set a minimum height for all bars? I tried editing the library directly, and it is possible to set a minimun height, but because the chart shows multiple bar sets, each with their own coordinates relative to the chart, they overlap.

[image]

Thank you!